# How to create graphs in gtk+

Tags: c++, user-interface, gtk

I have implemented a max flow algorithm, now i want to show it using gui in gtk+.
I want to display the residual graph.How can i do this in gtk+? I am coding in c++.

Answer (score 0):

You need a widget that can display graphs. There isn't one in plain vanilla GTK, so you'll have to find an external one. There are a few, I believe. If you happen to be using Python and PyGTK, you can use a Matplotlib graph in GTK.

Comment: is there one which i can use in c++?

Comment: Only half-finished ones in C, it would seem. (which you can still use from C++, of course) http://www.gtkforums.com/viewtopic.php?t=732 http://gtkgraph.sourceforge.net/index.html https://github.com/chergert/uber-graph